# insert ignore pandas dataframe into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I want to "insert ignore" an entire pandas dataframe into mysql. Is there a way to do this without looping over the rows?

In dataframe.to_sql I only see the option if_exists 'append' but will this still continue on duplicate unique keys?

Answer (score 18):

Consider using a temp table (with exact structure of final table) that is always replaced by pandas then run the `INSERT IGNORE` in a cursor call:

```
dataframe.to_sql('myTempTable', con, if_exists ='replace')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO myFinalTable SELECT * FROM myTempTable")
con.commit()
```

Comment: Replace the last 3 lines like this if you are using sqlalchemy:
`connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO myFinalTable SELECT * FROM myTempTable")
connection.close()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in pandas till the current version of `pandas (0.20.3)` .

The option `if_exists` applies only on table ( not on rows ) as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

```
if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
```

`fail`: If **table** exists, do nothing.

`replace`: If **table** exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.

`append`: If **table** exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.

Via Looping

This will slow down the process as you are inserting one row at a time

```
for x in xrange(data_frame.shape[0]):
    try:
        data_frame.iloc[x:x+1].to_sql(con=sql_engine, name="table_name", if_exists='append')
    except IntegrityError:
        # Your code to handle duplicates
        pass
```